# why aren't the options/flags working on my angular CLI?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I can't figure out why the options are not working. I've tried using:
--flat
--dryRun
--dry-run

but neither of those options perform.

on "ng --version" i get 7.16.0

this is what I type in and results

```
C:\projects\src\main\ui\app\modules\ac-dashboard>npm run ng generate component /modules/ac-dashboard/ac-dash --flat=true

> cust6@2.2.0 ng
> ng "generate" "component" "/modules/ac-dashboard/ac-dash"

CREATE src/main/ui/app/modules/ac-dashboard/ac-dash/ac-dash.component.html (22 bytes)
CREATE src/main/ui/app/modules/ac-dashboard/ac-dash/ac-dash.component.spec.ts (627 bytes)
CREATE src/main/ui/app/modules/ac-dashboard/ac-dash/ac-dash.component.ts (279 bytes)
CREATE src/main/ui/app/modules/ac-dashboard/ac-dash/ac-dash.component.scss (0 bytes)
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess that you're trying to use a flag for `modules` ('flat') when you're generating a `component`.

Try this:

```js
ng g component /modules/ac-dashboard/ac-dash --skip-Tests -is --dry-run
```

- skip-Test: For skipping test file
- is: For using `inline` styles

You can see all the options/flags you can use, with help command.
For instance:

```js
ng generate component --help
```

```js
ng generate module --help
```